wxWidgets не копирует DLL к исполняемому файлу
Использую CMake для подключения wxWidgets к проекту (билд из исходников). Всё компилируется, но программа не запускается из-за того, что отсутствуют DLL wxWidgets (Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135). Если скопировать DLL вручную, то программа запуститься. Если делать билд с set(wxBUILD_SHARED OFF), то программа, опять же, запустится нормально.
Как можно сделать так, чтобы DLL'ки сами копировались при билде в папку с exe?
Вот мой CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.30)
project(wxtest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(wxBUILD_SHARED ON)
add_subdirectory(./wx/)
add_executable(wxtest main.cpp)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
target_link_libraries(wxtest PUBLIC wx::core wx::base wx::net)

Исходный код wxWidgets скачан отсюда.
OS: Windows 11, компилятор: MinGW-w64, cmake version 3.30.2.


Вариант статической сборки, который у вас работает, чем не устраивает? 2. Можно прописать инструкции для установки вроде install(TARGETS wxlib DESTINATION ...) и после сборки выполнить установку. 3. Возможно, сразу стоит разобраться со сборкой пакета через CPack. P.S. а зачем вообще каждый раз для своего проекта собираться стороннюю библиотеку из исходников?


@user207200 1. Я не хочу, чтоб эезешник весил под 100мб. 2. С Install'ами я так и не разобрался. 3. Попробую,спасибо. P. S. Для того, чтобы проект можно было собрать на любую систему

Если что, переменная установка переменной CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY работает только на те таргеты, которые создавались после этой установки. Например, в Вашем коде эта установка не работает на таргеты, созданные в поддиректории wx/.
